# Protected method inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, protected

I have a simple C# code written after reading documentation about protected access modifier, but I am recieving a lot of illogical errors. I cant find any solutions to them.

```
using System;

public class WeaponController
{
    protected void Reload()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reload");
    }

    protected virtual void Shoot()
    {

    }
}

public class SMGController : WeaponController
{

    private override void Shoot()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Shoot");
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = new SMGController();
        test.Shoot();
        test.Reload();
    }
}
```

And I am recieving following errors:

> prog.cs(19,27): error CS0621: `SMGController.Shoot()': virtual or
>   abstract members cannot be private prog.cs(19,27): error CS0507:`
>   SMGController.Shoot()': cannot change access modifiers when
>   overriding `protected' inherited member`WeaponController.Shoot()'
>   prog.cs(10,25): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
>   Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings

If I will change access modifier of Shoot() method in SMGController to protected I recieve even more errors:

> prog.cs(30,8): error CS1540: Cannot access protected member
>   `WeaponController.Shoot()' via a qualifier of type`SMGController'.
>   The qualifier must be of type `Test' or derived from it
>   prog.cs(10,25): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
>   prog.cs(30,8): error CS0122:`WeaponController.Shoot()' is
>   inaccessible due to its protection level prog.cs(10,25): (Location of
>   the symbol related to previous error) prog.cs(31,8): error CS1540:
>   Cannot access protected member `WeaponController.Reload()' via a
>   qualifier of type`SMGController'. The qualifier must be of type
>   `Test' or derived from it prog.cs(5,17): (Location of the symbol
>   related to previous error) prog.cs(31,8): error CS0122:`
>   WeaponController.Reload()' is inaccessible due to its protection
>   level prog.cs(5,17): (Location of the symbol related to previous
>   error) Compilation failed: 4 error(s), 0 warnings

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You can't access `Reload` or `Shoot` from `Test` because they are `protected`. What don't you understand?

Comment: A protected member is accessible within its class AND by derived class instances.

Comment: @Владимир Yes, and `Test` is not a derived class.

Comment: `protected internal virtual void Shoot() {...}`, note `internal` let the method be called either from inherited class or from the *assembly* the method declared (your case). See https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `protected` methods from outside the class, i.e. call `WeaponController.Shoot` from `Test`.

Also, if you override a `protected` method, it has to be `protected`, too.

Obviously, you want `Reload` and `Shoot` to be `public`, so you can call them from `Test.Main`.

Comment: Due to this: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected) _A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances._ So why test, being instance of inherited class cant call his methods?

Comment: Test doesn't inherit from SMGController or WeaponController.  To do that, you would have to declare it as `public class Test : SMGController`.

Answer (score 1):

The `protected` modifier means that **only** the class itself or a subclass can access `Shoot`.

You are trying to access it from some other class `Test` that has no inheritance relation with both `SMGController` and `WeaponController`, and such access is forbidden by the `protected` modifier.

For reference, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected, especially this line in the first section:

> A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.

You can fix this by making `Shoot` `public`. Or if you insist on keeping it `protected`, then you would need to add a method e.g. `public PublicShoot()` that then calls the protected method.

Comment: So why test being an instance of SMGController can not call its methods?

Comment: `public class Test` does not have explicit inheritance specified, and that means that it inherits from class `Object`.